# Is 'YYYYQ' a valid DATETIME format for SQL? And if so, how do I make it with my data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have some tables in a postgres that have a column for year and a column for quarter (both stored as bigint).  I need to be able to combine those together in the output of a query in the form of 'YYYYQ' (not the hard part) AND have the datatype of that field be datetime (<--the hard part).

The only query I have attempted that didn't fail was -

```
SELECT to_date((year::VARCHAR + quarter::VARCHAR),'YYYYQ') AS Stuff 
FROM company.products
```

And while the output is in DATETIME format, there is no Quarter info in it.

Sample -

| stuff |
| --- |
| 2011-01-01 |
| 2011-01-01 |
| 2012-01-01 |
| 2012-01-01 |
| 2012-01-01 |

Is it even possible to create output that has the format 'YYYYQ' ***AND*** is in DATETIME format?  And if so, how?

Comment: How do you expect to use the quarter information in the resulting date time? Eg should Q1 default to January 1st, Q2 defaults to April 1, etc?

Comment: Dates are stored in an internal format.  That format is not YYYYQ, so you cannot do what the question asks.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the date of the 1st day of the quarter. Multiply the recorded quarter -1 by 3.

```sql
SELECT to_date('2021','YYYY') + interval '6 month';
      ?column?
---------------------
 2021-07-01 00:00:00

SELECT to_char(to_date('2021','YYYY') + interval '6 month','YYYYQ');
 to_char
---------
 20213


SELECT q, 
 to_char(to_date('2021','YYYY') + interval '3 month'*(q-1),'YYYYQ') as YYYYQ,
 to_date('2021','YYYY') + interval '3 month'*(q-1) as d
FROM generate_series(1,4) f(q);

 q | yyyyq |          d
---+-------+---------------------
 1 | 20211 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00
 2 | 20212 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00
 3 | 20213 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00
 4 | 20214 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) (emphasis mine):

> In `to_timestamp` and `to_date`, weekday names or numbers (DAY, D, and related field types) are accepted but are ***ignored*** for purposes of computing the result. ***The same is true for quarter (Q) fields.***

Comment: [JGH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67693905/634824) shows a solution and is a better answer than mine.

Comment: No Matt. While JGH's shows OP how to get the results he wants, yours shows *why* their attempt did not work. That is at least as important.